# Pattern matching in a string represented by char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to solve a really basic problem using just arrays (text is array of chars), but I have an issue implementing something particular.

So, I am trying to write a function that takes two character arrays as parameters - namely, text and pattern - and returns the number of times the pattern occurs in the text (how many different substrings of the text match the pattern). The text is composed only of digits and Latin letters. The pattern may contain the following special characters (which cannot appear in the text):

"*" - corresponds to exactly one arbitrary character;
"%" - corresponds to one or two digits (from the decimal numeral system);
"@" - corresponds to one Latin letter.

Let's analyze some examples:

```
text: "te3t zdrte44q t33t"

pattern: "t\*%@"
```

Explanation:

The pattern "t*%@" can match substrings like "te3a", "t337q", etc. * corresponds to exactly one arbitrary character, % corresponds to one or two digits, and @ corresponds to one Latin letter.

In the given text "te3t zdrte44q t33t", the pattern matches three substrings: "te3t", "te44q", and "t33t".

Therefore, the expected output for this example is 3.

```
text: "aaaaaa"

pattern: "aa"

Expected output: 5
```

....

```
text: "123"

pattern: "%%"

Expected output: 3
```

I've made good progress with the pattern symbols * and @. They're working well, matching exactly one character as expected. However, I've hit a bit of a roadblock with %. Unlike the others, it can match not just one but sometimes two symbols, and it's giving me a bit of a headache.

See, the tricky part is that % doesn't have a fixed length. It's variable, so it can match one symbol in one instance and two in another. Figuring out how to handle this dynamic matching is proving to be a bit challenging for me right now.

If you've got any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this, I'd really appreciate your input.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE_TEXT = 201;
const int MAX_SIZE_PATTERN = 201;

unsigned getStrLen(char str[])
{
    int i = 0, count = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

bool isLetter(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}

bool isDigit(char ch)
{
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}

unsigned countMatches(char text[], char pattern[])
{
    int textLen = getStrLen(text);
    int patternLen = getStrLen(pattern);

    int i = 0, j = 0, currentLen = 0, matches = 0;

    bool matchedASingleDigit = false;
    while (i < textLen)
    {
        cout << text[i] << "?=" << pattern[j] << endl;
        if (text[i] == pattern[j] || pattern[j] == '*' 
            || (pattern[j] == '@' && isLetter(text[i])))
        {
            cout << "(before) i=" << i << "; j=" << j << endl;
            currentLen += 1;
            i++;
            j++;
            cout << "(after) i=" << i << "; j=" << j << endl;

            cout << "currentLen = " << currentLen << endl;
            if (currentLen == patternLen)
            {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        else if (pattern[j] == '%')
        {
            /*if (isDigit(text[i]))
            {
                matchedASingleDigit = true;
                currentLen += 1;
                i++;
                j++;
                cout << "(after) i=" << i << "; j=" << j << endl;

                cout << "currentLen = " << currentLen << endl;
                if (currentLen == patternLen)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
            }

            if (i < textLen - 1 && isDigit[text])*/
        }
        else
        {
            i -= currentLen - 1;
            j = 0;
            cout << "(after) i=" << i << "; j=" << j << endl;
            
            currentLen = 0;
            cout << "currentLen = " << currentLen << endl;
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

void testCountingMatches()
{
    char text[MAX_SIZE_TEXT];
    cin.getline(text, MAX_SIZE_TEXT);

    char pattern[MAX_SIZE_PATTERN];
    cin.getline(pattern, MAX_SIZE_PATTERN);

    unsigned matches = countMatches(text, pattern);

    cout << matches << endl;
}

int main()
{
    testCountingMatches();  
}
```

Comment: What is dot? Do you mean @?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, yep, my mistake, sorry! Gonna fix it.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and observe exactly how its logic works, at what point did your program's actual logic began to diverge from your expected logic, and why? Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik,  right now, my main challenge lies in figuring out how to handle the % symbol in my code. As I mentioned earlier, it can match either one or two symbols, and this dynamic behavior is causing a bit of confusion for me. Don't see what exactly made someone like your comment and how debugging helps when you don't know how to approach a problem.

Comment: One approach would be [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). For each `%` sign, you attempt to match it as two digits, and proceed with the rest of the pattern; and then go back and try again, matching it as one digit this time.

Comment: This should be painfully obvious. Whenever `%` is encountered in the search pattern, it is necessary to count the number of consecutive `%` characters, which will be at least 1. Then, make a trivial observation: this will match any number of digits between `n` and `n*2` (`n` is the number of consecutive `%` characters). So: start gobbling up digits in the search string. You must get at least `n`, else matching fails. When `n*2` digits are skipped, resume with the next matching character.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Greedy matching won't necessarily find all occurrences of the pattern. Or in fact, might not find a match at all: consider the string `12` and the pattern `%*` or `%2`

Comment: In that case, what's being asked here is to basically implement a regular expression matching engine. This is not a walk in a park. It's actually a pretty advanced topic. I would expect that if something like this is given in a C++ class the class instructor or teacher should've explained all the nuances and the necessary logic of a regular expression matching engine. This is not something that's typically assigned in an introductory C++ situation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks for the idea! May you be a little more specific though? Maybe providing an example, so I can understand.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Regular expression matching is easy. Efficient regular expression matching is hard.

Comment: The last case is tricky. There are 3 substring that match the pattern, but one of them matches in two different ways. So a naïve implementation that counts ways to match won't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, you can use recursion.

```
bool matchSingle(char text[], char pattern[], int remainLen)
{
    if(remainLen < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(text[0] == '\0' || pattern[0]=='\0')
    {
        return pattern[0]=='\0' && remainLen == 0;
    }
    if (text[0] == pattern[0] || pattern[0] == '*' 
            || (pattern[0] == '@' && isLetter(text[0])))
    {
        return matchSingle(text + 1, pattern + 1, remainLen - 1);
    }
    else if(pattern[0] == '%')
    {
        if(!isDigit(text[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(matchSingle(text + 1, pattern + 1, remainLen - 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(isDigit(text[1]) && matchSingle(text + 2, pattern + 1, remainLen - 2))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

unsigned countMatches(char text[], char pattern[])
{
    int textLen = getStrLen(text);
    int patternLen = getStrLen(pattern);

    int i = 0, j = 0, currentLen = 0, matches = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < getStrLen(text); i++){
        for(j = getStrLen(pattern); j <= getStrLen(text) - i; j++){            
            matches += matchSingle(text + i, pattern, j));
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Here we first factor out the counting for different `i` to its own function, then we can make use of recursion to advance both the text and pattern pointer. I have kept the code as close to your original as possible. In the refactored function we only care about exact matches and in the `countMatches` function we enumerate all possible lengths. Inefficient as it is, this should be able to handle the `text: 3333, pattern: %3%` case in the comment.

Now as @n.m.couldbeanAI commented, it is not that easy to make pattern matching efficient. This is not meant to be efficient, just to give you the idea since you are stuck.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/PWjbhbjKK

Some additional notes for your code:

Don't use `using namespace std`.
It may seem convenient for now, but sooner or later its going to bite back, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more details.
In this case, all you need from the `std` namespace are `cout`, `cin` and `endl`. So you should either spell out the full name of `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::endl` everywhere (my preference), or if you don't want to type them anywhere, use

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

instead.

Also you don't actually need `std::endl` at those places, you should just use `'\n'` instead because `std::endl` causes unnecessary flushes.

Additionally, don't write C-style C++. C++ standard library has already offered a lot of tools you can use. If your teacher is one of those who restrict their students from using the C++ standard library, then he is not really teaching C++ properly and I feel sorry for it. Regardless of whether that is the fact, you need to know how to use the standard library.

For example, you should use `std::string` instead of raw char arrays with a fixed length. Then you don't need to worry about whether `MAX_SIZE_TEXT` is large enough or not. Regardless of whether you choose to use raw char array or not, there is no reason to write `getStrLen` yourself unless it is explicitly required. You should just use `std::string::size()` if you choose `std::string`, or `std::strlen()` if you want to stick to raw char array. There is also `std::isdigit()` although that one is trickier to use without introducing subtle bugs in your program.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as far as I see the case "te3t zdrte44q t33t" doesn't work.

Comment: @SAQ Fixed and added  some advices.

Comment: [Still not quite correct](https://godbolt.org/z/q7xfK4jKT).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI In that case, may be it's necessary to store the indices for the matched strings and then uniquify them later.

Comment: That's exactly the problem.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Should be OK now.

Comment: Yeah. But now the algo is cubic.